# Print multidimensional array in Perl, with keys

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash

I have this kind of array in Perl:

```
my $foo_bar;

$foo_bar->{"foo"} //= [];
push @{$foo_bar->{"foo"}}, "foo1";
push @{$foo_bar->{"foo"}}, "foo2";
push @{$foo_bar->{"foo"}}, "foo3";

$foo_bar->{"bar"} //= [];
push @{$foo_bar->{"bar"}}, "bar1";
push @{$foo_bar->{"bar"}}, "bar2";
push @{$foo_bar->{"bar"}}, "bar3";
```

The result I'm trying to get is:

- foo: foo1, foo2, foo3
- bar: bar1, bar2, bar3

I have no idea.. I'm trying this:

```
  foreach my $fb(@$foo_bar){

  }
```

I'm getting an error:

> Not an ARRAY reference at ./test.pl line 417,  line 1000.

Comment: Which one is line 1000?

Comment: `$foo_bar` is a hashref, not an arrayref

Comment: That's a good question.. there is no 1000 line in the scirpt. 417 line is: `foreach my $fb(@$foo_bar){`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the 417. It's probably because you have an open filehandle. If so, don't use global filehandles (`INFILE`). Use lexical filehandles (`$fh`) instead.

Comment: `$foo_bar->{"foo"} //= [];` lines are not needed. Perl autovivifies the structures when needed (and sometimes when not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate `$foo_bar` as a hash ref, not as an array ref. And because it's a hash, you need to get the keys first and then work with them.

```
use feature 'say';

#                 | you only iterate the keys ...
#                 |    | this percent is for hash  
#                 V    V     
foreach my $key ( keys %{ $foo_bar } ) {

    #    | ... and use the key here 
    #    |                   | this one is an array ref
    #    |                   |  | ... and the value here
    #    |                   |  |
    #    V                   V  VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    say "$key ", join( ', ', @{ $foo_bar->{$key} } );
}
```

It helps to use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) or [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) to look at your data structure. This one is Data::Printer, which is good for human consumption.

```
 \ {                  # curly braces are hash refs
    bar   [           # square braces are array refs   
        [0] "bar1",
        [1] "bar2",
        [2] "bar3"
    ],
    foo   [
        [0] "foo1",
        [1] "foo2",
        [2] "foo3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @robertwojnar note that this will get the keys in arbitrary order; if you want foo first, then bar, you need to explictly do that: `foreach my $key ( 'foo', 'bar' )` or keep the desired order in a separate array

Comment: I think ysth meant if you need them in a *specific* order.